# How to fix 'Invalid Provider' error in IONIC 2

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm tryng to add a QRScanner plugin in my IONIC CORDOVA project; so I run

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-qrscanner`

`npm install --save @ionic-native/qr-scanner`

inside my project folder.

Then in `app.module.ts` I've added

`import {QRScannerOriginal}from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner'`

and in `providers`:

```py
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    Splashscreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    QRScannerOriginal
  ]
```

Can you give me some help?

When I run the project with `ionic serve` I receive this runtime error:

```py
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [StatusBar, Splashscreen, [object Object], ?undefined?]
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:31780:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:31744:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:31527:50)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:31410:29)
    at RuntimeCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:47996:41)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:47966:35)
    at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:47956:21)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:33638:25)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:33620:21)
```

Comment: Maybe this help you https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/issues/224

Comment: Please try by importing `QRScanner` instead like this `import {QRScanner} from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';`

Comment: Fixed! I've changed my import in `import {QRScanner} from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner/ngx';` in app.module.ts and in the other `.ts` page i've used it.
Thanks.